# How to use vw and vh css with React Native

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

I'm creating a basic login using `React Native` with a logo and 2 inputs:

```
//import liraries
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Image } from 'react-native';

// create a component
class Login extends Component {
    render() {
        const imageURL = require('./images/CircleLogo.png');
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.loginContainer}>
                    <Image resizeMode="contain" style={styles.logo} source={imageURL} />
                </View>
                <View style={styles.formContainer}>
                    <LoginForm /> 
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

// define your styles
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'aliceblue',
    },
    loginContainer:{
        alignItems: 'center',
        flexGrow: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center'
    },
    logo: {
        position: 'absolute',
        width: '70vw',
        height: '70vw',
        maxWidth: 300
    }
});

//make this component available to the app
export default Login;
```

As you can see i am using `vw` and `vh` css measurements.

This works on the web, but not on iOS or Android.

**Does anyone have a good suggestion for handling `vw` and `vh` measurements?**

Side Note: It appears react accepts percentages as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33939974/make-view-80-width-of-parent-in-react-native), which I may revert to. But my question pertains to specifically the `vw` and `vh` measurements.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't know if react-native supports viewport units. But, there's a module:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-viewport-units

Install

```
npm install react-native-viewport-units --save
```

Usage

```
var {vw, vh, vmin, vmax} = require('react-native-viewport-units');
```

Notice the required operator/syntax: x * vw

```
<View style={{height:50*vh, width:50*vw}}/>
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  lookingGood: {
    width: 15*vmin,
    height: 10*vmax,
    padding: 2*vw,
    margin: 4*vh,
  }
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work in my device...

Answer (score 29):

Instead of veiwport you can use Dimensions in react-native. PFB the link of react-native Dimensions.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/dimensions

Here is an example:

```jsx
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native'

const halfWindowsWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width / 2
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! Instead of adding an extra dependency it is save and easy to rely on react-natives preferred `useWindowDimensions` API. It will propagate updates and works seamlessly with react-native-web since v0.12.0.

Comment: Super legit! This is a great way to go about it.

Comment: Also package `react-native-viewport-units` breaks on Next JS (Server Side Rendering) at import level, leading to lazy load complication for nothing.

Comment: Could you precise exactly what happens if the users changes window size or device orientation ?

Answer (score 8):

**Viewport units: vw, vh, vmin, vmax - React Native.**

https://github.com/joetakara/react-native-expo-viewport-units

**Install**

```
npm install react-native-expo-viewport-units
```

or

```
yarn add react-native-expo-viewport-units
```

**Usage**

```
import { vw, vh, vmin, vmax } from 'react-native-expo-viewport-units';

<View style={{ width: vw(100), height: vh(100) }}>
  ...
<View>
```

Answer (score 2):

I've browsed through other answers, all that works and simple for new projects. If you desire to make an existing project responsive, I'd recommend using the below package.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-responsive-view-port

Assume you've already built an app for 1280 x 800 and you wish to make it responsive for all resolutions, then you can achieve it as shown below.

**Before**

```
    <View style={{ width:500 }} ></View>
```

**After**

```
const { vw, vh } = createViewPortConfig({ width : 1280, height : 800 });

<View style={{ width: 500*vw }} ></View>
```

I find this method easier than recalculating all sizes.