# React Native bottom navbar full width

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to make a bottom navbar in React Native but it isn't spanning the full width, only the width of its content. I have tried using vw as in [How to use vw and vh css with React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52449976/how-to-use-vw-and-vh-css-with-react-native) but it gives the error: "width":<> is not usable as native method argument.

AppBar:

```
import { View, Pressable, Text } from "react-native"

const AppBar = ({ style, addNote }) => {
  return (
    <View style={style}>
      <Pressable
        onPress={() => addNote({ id: "9", title: "Hii", body: "new note" })}
      >
        <Text style={{ textAlign: "center", fontSize: 30 }}>Add</Text>
      </Pressable>
    </View>
  )
}

export default AppBar
```

style:

```
appbar: {
    position: "absolute",
    bottom: 0,
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "center",

    flexGrow: 1,
    flexShrink: 1,
    marginRight: "auto",
  },
```

How can I get the AppBar to span the full width?

Comment: Have you tried `width: '100%'` or `alignSelf: 'stretch'`?

Comment: Thanks, width 100% works, not alignSelf: stretch. I thought that you couldn't use % in react native