# How Do I Make ScrollView Components Size a Ratio of Screen Size in React Native?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, mobile

I'm working with React Native and I have a `ScrollView` with a small, finite number of Components (hence why I'm not using `FlatList`).

As best as I can tell, I need to provide a `height` to the components for them to be big enough to render in the `ScrollView` and hardcoding the `height` with just pixels seems to work.

[Screenshot of the height as 250 pixels.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uU4t6.png)

I've also just found that [you can use a percentage for height/width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33939974/make-view-80-width-of-parent-in-react-native). But when I try doing this for my components within my `ScrollView`, the components all become diminutive.

[Screenshot of height as 25% not working.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rlSf.png)

I get that the components might behave differently in a `ScrollView` as opposed to in a normal `View`, so I was wondering if we have to specify the exact number of pixels for each Component or if there's a better way to do this.

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {SafeAreaView, ScrollView, StyleSheet, View} from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    item: {
        height: 250,
        // height: '25%' <--- Doesn't work
        margin: 2,
        borderRadius: 15
    },
})

const Item = ({color}) => (
    <View style={[styles.item,
        {backgroundColor: color}]}/>
  );

class App extends Component {

    render = () => {
        return (
            <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
                <ScrollView  style={{flex: 1}}>
                    <Item color={'chocolate'} />
                    <Item color={'darkseagreen'} />
                    <Item color={'khaki'} />
                    <Item color={'palegreen'} />
                    <Item color={'paleturquoise'} />
                    <Item color={'aqua'} />
                </ScrollView>
            </SafeAreaView>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you better use `Dimensions` from React Native

```
import {SafeAreaView, ScrollView, StyleSheet, View, Dimensions} from 'react-native';


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    item: {
        height: Dimensions.get('window').height * 0.25,
        margin: 2,
        borderRadius: 15
    },
})
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you!